# Parsing a File in Java

Tags: java, dropbox-api, text-parsing

im using the dropbox api. When i ask the api to get file listings from my account, it gives me this meta data which isn't in any particular format that i know of:

`magnum-opus.txt: File("/magnum-opus.txt", iconName="page_white_text", mightHaveThumbnail=false, numBytes=17734, humanSize="17.3 KB", lastModified="2014/01/27 05:19:30 UTC", clientMtime="2014/01/27 05:19:30 UTC", rev="11e6c9e5e")`

Since im not that good with strings i was hoping if someone could help me find a way to extract at least the filename ("/magnum-opus.txt"), and the 'lastmodified' and 'humansize' bits from above. Please and thank you :)

Comment: Java or C++? Please pick one.

Comment: either, i just need a way to do it :)

Comment: Maybe you should try to get better with strings. That's a pretty bad excuse.

Comment: Can there be a way to pick both answers, doesn't seem fair to pick only one, both a great ways to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using one of the metadata methods in the official Java SDK (like [getMetadata](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxClient.html#getMetadata%28java.lang.String%29)) it sounds like you're doing toString and trying to manually parse this, which is unnecessary. This metadata method returns a [DbxEntry](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxEntry.html) (which you can convert to [DbxEntry.File](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxEntry.File.html) using [asFile](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxEntry.html#asFile%28%29). You can then directly access the information you want on that object. E.g.:

```
    DbxEntry.File fileInfo;
    try {
        fileInfo = dbxClient.getMetadata("/test.txt").asFile();
    }
    catch (DbxException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Error in getMetadata(): " + ex.getMessage());
        System.exit(1); return;
    }
    System.out.println("fileInfo name: " + fileInfo.name);
    System.out.println("fileInfo lastModified: " + fileInfo.lastModified);
    System.out.println("fileInfo humanSize: " + fileInfo.humanSize);
```

Comment: whoa i don't know how i could have missed that, thanks again!! @Greg

Answer (score 1):

Just String-playing...

```
String in = "magnum-opus.txt: File(\"/magnum-opus.txt\", iconName=\"page_white_text\", mightHaveThumbnail=false, numBytes=17734, humanSize=\"17.3 KB\", lastModified=\"2014/01/27 05:19:30 UTC\", clientMtime=\"2014/01/27 05:19:30 UTC\", rev=\"11e6c9e5e\")";
String insideParenth = in.substring(in.indexOf("(")+1, in.length()-1);
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(insideParenth, ", ");
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    Map<String,String> properties = new HashMap<String,String>();
    String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
    if(token.contains("=")){
        token = token.replaceAll("\"", "");
        String left= token.substring(0, token.indexOf("="));
        String right=token.substring(token.indexOf("=")+1);
        properties.put(left,right );
        System.out.println("left:["+left+"] and right=[" + right + "]");        
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
left:[iconName] and right=[page_white_text]
left:[mightHaveThumbnail] and right=[false]
left:[numBytes] and right=[17734]
left:[humanSize] and right=[17.3]
left:[lastModified] and right=[2014/01/27]
left:[clientMtime] and right=[2014/01/27]
left:[rev] and right=[11e6c9e5e]
```

EDIT:

```
String titleWithPath, titleWithoutPath;

insideParenth = in.substring(in.indexOf("(")+1, in.length()-1); 
titleWithPath = insideParenth.substring(insideParenth.indexOf("\"")+1, insideParenth.indexOf(",")‌​-1); 
System.out.println(titleWithPath); //Prints out: "/magnum-opus.txt" 

String titleWithoutPath = insideParenth.substring(insideParenth.indexOf("/")+1, insideParenth.indexOf(",")-1 ); 
System.out.println(titleWithoutPath); //Prints out: "magnum-opus.txt"
```

Comment: Can there be a way to extract "/magnum-opus.txt" as well?

Comment: Added a few lines ^__^

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciate it mahn!

Answer (score 0):

First remove the part of the string up to the `File(`

```
String theString = "magnum-opus.txt: File("/magnum-opus.txt", iconName="page_white_text", mightHaveThumbnail=false, numBytes=17734, humanSize="17.3 KB", lastModified="2014/01/27 05:19:30 UTC", clientMtime="2014/01/27 05:19:30 UTC", rev="11e6c9e5e")";

theString = theString.replaceAll("^.*.File\\(","");
```

then remove the last character the "(".

```
theString = theString.replaceAll("\\)","");
```

Then you could just perform splits to get the information

```
HashMap<String,String> results = new HashMap<String,String>();
String[] arr = theString.split(",");
for(String s : arr) {
  s = s.replace("\"","");
  s = s.trim();
  if(s.contains("=")) {
     String[] tmp = s.split("=");
     results.put(tmp[0],tmp[1]);
  }
  else {
    results.put("filename",s);
  }
}
```

The above should produce a HashMap of key, values from that string.

Comment: it gives me an error on the line with: 

'String[] arr = theString.split(',');'

it says no suitable method found for split(char)

Comment: @Javed Use double quotes.

Comment: @Javed yes my mistake, single quotes implies a char type. Double quotes is string

Comment: Thanks this has been a great help!!